# Words with prefix apo-

Tags: etymology

From etymonline, the two following words seem to have the same etymology:

> apocalypse: apo- "from" (see apo-) + kalyptein "to cover, conceal"
>   (see Calypso).
>
> apocryphal: apo- "away" (see apo-) + kryptein "to hide" (see crypt).

But the two seem to have opposite meanings.*apocalypse* means revelation and uncovering, while *apocryphal* means spurious.

How shall I understand them?

Comment: You've oversimplified apo. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apo-  It can also indicate derivation. Hence apocryphal, cryptic derivation or of dubious authorship. Whereas in apocalypse, apo indicates absence: absence of concealment.

Comment: It may also be worth noting what etymonline says about ***apo-*** in relation to ***apoplexy*** - [from apo- "off" (see apo-), in this case **probably an intensive prefix**, + plessein "hit"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=apoplexy&searchmode=none). Let's face it, an *apocalypse* is a pretty *intensive* "revelation".

Answer (score 3):

**Apocalypse** means in fact "put away the cover", that is "removing the cover", and then things will be revealed (cf "book of Revelations").

**Apocryphal** means "hidden away", because they are not to be read. In fact, apocryphal Gospels would be extremely dangerous for Christian believers : the one from St-James mentions explicitly that Jesus had brothers and sisters (and not in a symbolic meaning) and married St-Magdalena ; the one by St-Peter, yes, himself, does not mention the Resurrection, etc..

*The word does not mean by itself "spurious"*, but if it was impossible to deny their existence - they were too well known, at least you could deny their authenticity and forbid their reading.

**Apogee** means "away from earth" and applied initially to the moon.

**Apotheosis** means "put away to rejoin the gods".

ETC.

**You see that "apo" is always used in the consistent meaning of "away, off"**

Comment: I used to make the same mistake: It isn't "Revelations," it's "Revelation," singular. I don't think "apocryphal " means "hidden away." Greek likely doesn't use the same intensifier that we use in English: "hide away." And I sure don't think "apocryphal" advocates a policy of "hiding away" apocryphal books. Rather, it is descriptive. "Derived from the hidden" seems more likely. And the Gospel of Peter doesn't deny the Resurrection, but its heresy is that it implies Jesus did not really suffer. The Resurrection is described, but it's bizarre, involving a talking cross coming out of the tomb.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

The explanation that I have worked out (and that is alluded to in your question itself) is as follows:

***apocryphal*** derives from the noun ***crypt*** meaning vault. Short of an explosion you cannot *do away* with a vault. So *apo-cryphal* here can only mean *away/off **in** the crypt*.

***apocalypse*** on the other hand derives from the Greek action verb *kalyptein* meaning *conceal* - thus meaning *away/off/un conceal* or *reveal.*

In other words *apo-* modifies a physical object in the first and an action verb in the second.

Comment: "apocryphal derives from the noun crypt" — you have any source to back that up? GR says the noun _crypt_ derives from a Greek verb that means _to hide_, and the etymoline reference in the question mentions that _apocryphal_ comes form the same verb.

Comment: We often think our language, English, has the corner on synonyms, but my take away is that Greek has two verbs, "kalyptein" and "kryptein" that mean, respectively "to cover or conceal" and "to hide." The difference between these concepts in both languages is a matter of barely meaningful or detectable nuances.

Answer (score 0):

OED:

> **apo-**, prefix
>
> Representing Greek ἀπο- off, from, away; quite.
>
> **1. In compounds already formed in Greek, or others analogous to them.**
>
> **2. In modern scientific words, not on Greek analogies, with sense of ‘standing off or away from each other, detached, separate,’ as apo-carpous.**

E.g.

> **apocalypse,** Etymology: < Latin apocalypsis, < Greek ἀποκάλυψις, noun of action < ἀποκαλύπτειν to uncover, disclose, < ἀπό off + καλύπτειν to cover.
>
> **apodiabolosis**, Etymology: < Greek διάβολος devil, on the model of apotheosis. **Lowering to the rank of a devil; a making or treating as diabolical.**
>
> **apodyterium**, Etymology: Latin, < Greek ἀποδυτήριον, < ἀποδύειν to put off, undress.
> **The apartment in which clothes were deposited by those who were preparing for the bath or palæstra; hence gen. a dressing-room, a robing-room.**

Answer (score -2):

"Apoptosis" describes cellular senescence, or a natural, *programmed* cell death, as opposed to necrosis.  The former represents an ordered, predictable process of cell death, whereas the latter represents the potential for pathology.  The prefix "apo" means to *fall away from.*  The suffix "ptosis" means *to droop*.  What is most remarkable is the mispronunciation of apoptosis.  Since the initial **p** is silent in the **p**tosis, it is also silent in apo**p**tosis.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was actually asked, and your logic is flawed regarding the pronunciation; you're falling into the etymological fallacy trap. The p is only silent in _ptosis_ because /pt/ is not phonotactically valid in English. /əpt/, on the other hand, is perfectly valid, and there's no real reason not to pronounce the p in _apoptosis_ (except that that is a common pronunciation). If etymology were a guide to pronunciation, the p in _helicopter_ would also be silent, which of course it isn't.